# Join tables when a value isn't there in the left table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got 2 tables with some data and trying to join them when the value isn't there in the clients table and also in the custom_clients table. It works fine when the joining the table when a value isn't in the custom_clients table, but doesn't when the value isn't there in the clients table.

```
clients
id language_id key            text
1   1        client_account   new account
2   2        client_signin    signin


custom_clients
id language_id key            text
1   1        client_name      name
2   2        client_signin    login

The output should be a table like
language_id key            text
1        client_account   new account
1        client_name      name
2        client_signin    login
```

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT language_id, key, text FROM clients 
INNER JOIN custom_clients ON custom_clients.language_id = clients.language_id
```

Comment: Please check your question, it doesn’t make any sense

Comment: You want one of the OUTER joins for this then COALESCE the columns

Comment: @Ernesto If you read it for a few minutes, the question is clear, but agree that the requirements were not spelled out so well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach uses a full outer join:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(cc.language_id, c.language_id) AS language_id,
    COALESCE(cc."key", c."key") AS "key",
    COALESCE(cc.text, c.text) AS text
FROM clients c
FULL OUTER JOIN custom_clients cc
    ON cc.language_id = c.language_id AND
       cc."key" = c."key";
```

### Demo

EDIT:

This can be simplified a little bit with the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT language_id, "key",
       COALESCE(cc.text, c.text) AS text
FROM clients c FULL OUTER JOIN
     custom_clients cc
     USING (language_id, "key");
```

Comment: No need to coalesce on the columns that are part of the JOIN, I think? Only need to COALESCE `text`?

Comment: @sabik I disagree.  The whole point of the outer join is that one table, but not the other, might have a join key not present in the other table.

Comment: Ah, of course; you're right. Need to COALESCE all columns.